# Display DropDown list from db column ASP.NET MVC4 + Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, html-select

I have 2 tables in the DB: `Car` and `CarType`.

For `CarType` I store 2 columns:

1. ID `int`
2. Type `string`

Now I want to be able to make a DropDown filter which will have the Types from the `Type` column in the `CarType` table.

And when I select the desired Type and press Filter to display the information, it should show only about the Cars from the Car table that are that Type.

I'm using VS2012 and building MVC4 InternetApp with EF.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Car",FormMethod.Get)){ Html.DropDownList(ViewData["Types"]) */} <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> }
```

Controller:

```
List<SelectListItem> tipovi = new List<SelectListItem>(); 
List<SelectListItem> types = new List<SelectListItem>(); 
var _db = new CarsContext(); 
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> types = _db.Car.Select(ct => new SelectListItem { Value = ct.ID.ToString(), Text = ct.FK_CarType.ToString() }); 
ViewData["Types"] = types;
```

Comment: I've tried several tutorials... but nothing match my problem... I'm new to this and I'm asking for "F1" :)

Comment: View:
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Car",FormMethod.Get)){    
         Html.DropDownList(ViewData["Types"])  */}
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    }
Controller:
List<SelectListItem> tipovi = new List<SelectListItem>();
List<SelectListItem> types = new List<SelectListItem>();
var _db = new CarsContext();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> types = _db.Car.Select(ct => new SelectListItem
{
 Value = ct.ID.ToString(),
    Text = ct.FK_CarType.ToString()
    });
    ViewData["Types"] = types;